# Importing games.request

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm using `Android Studio` and tried to import Google Play Game Services into my application.

Imported BaseGameUtils folder in the libraries and now I have an error at the following line, in the GameHelper class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.request.GameRequest;
```

More exactly, it says `"cannot resolve symbol: request."`

I'm pretty new to android development and android studio so sorry if it's a lousy question.

**Edit 1**

Ok, so i did what Scott Barta told me, but still got a `"cannot resolve symbol: GameRequest."`.
On a simmilar topic i found that i should go to Project Structure -> modules -> dependencies -> plus sign -> module dependency and add my libraries file there as well.

Did that, and i got this:

`"Gradle project refrsh failed: Cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError"`

Other things i did was go to settings.gradle and add a

```
include ":libraries:BaseGameUtils"
```

In the build.gradle i added, in the dependencies tree

```
compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
```

Comment: Hmm, post your full build.gradle files. After following the GUI steps in my answer adding the lines manually to the build files should have been redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem.  What fixed it for me was updating the google play-services to a newer version.  Check your build.gradle file and see if it's using an older version in the dependencies.  If so, try replacing it with

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3+'

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're including the Google Play Services library, but the correct way is:

- Ensure that the "Google Repository" is installed in the SDK manager
- File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > + button > Library dependency,
  then choose "Google Play Services" from the list.
  [image]

Comment: Did what you asked me, but got stuck again. Edited main post.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually executing gradle from your app directory to get more information about what's going wrong.

`./gradlew --info --stacktrace assembleDebug`