# Getting started with Google Play Services, Cannot Resolve Symbol

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am developing a Android Studio project using gradle 2.2 and Google Play Services 12.0.1. I am now trying to add functionality from Google Play Services.

The thing is I am unable to import the Google Play Service library. When I try the following line.

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
```

Or anything similar i get "Cannot resolve symbol Games", Android Studio proposes "Add library <...> to classpath" but that does not seem to change anything.

**What I have done so far**

I started out following [this setup guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). Which simply says to update your build.gradle. My top-level build.gradle contains this,

```
project(":android") {
  apply plugin: "android"
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  configurations { natives }

  dependencies {
      compile project(":core")
      compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
      < ... >
      compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:12.0.1"
    }
 }
```

I have also ensured that the buildscript section contains the maven link. I have also checked that Google Play Services are installed from the "SDK Tools" pane in the SDK manager. In addition to this I have added the correct version of Play Services as a dependency in Project structure -> Modules -> Dependencies. Someone suggested on earlier Stack Overflow questions that adding

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

to the AndroidManifest might help, so my Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="wizard_team.wizards_tale" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="wizard_team.wizards_tale.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

I do not receive any error messages when I resync and I have tried to update and restart Android Studio several times. I have also tried "Invalidate chaches/restart..".

During my quest on Google I have found several people experiencing the same problem and I have tried their solutions but nothing has worked. I have spent way to long with this problem, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Recheck the instructions on which build.gradle - it seems the play-services should be specified in the app-level build.gradle.

Comment: I recommend you try first with QuickStart, its very fast to make it functional. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

Comment: Have tried moving the dependencies to app-level build.gradle, no change.

Comment: You may refer with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113726/importing-games-request) which suggested to update the google play-services to a newer version. Also ensure that the "Google Repository" is installed in the SDK manager. Likewise, this [forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/resolve-symbol-problem-t3508946) recommended to do `gradlew clean` and `gradlew build`.

Comment: I am also getting this with analytics google service. Trying to track down a google issue. Or some solution. I have added maven google repo and google() to all different parts of build.gradle files with no success. @Gotiasits that quickstart guide is using old version of google play services. I notice a lot of their documentation and samples are outdated a bit.

Comment: @abielita There is no newer version and gradlew clean and build runs just fine

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. As I do not have much experience creating apps I tried importing google play services into the core-module part of my app. For anyone else just getting started, the android specific code such as this should go in android -> java -> [package-name].

Might seem trivial, but as a beginner using [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) setup tool this problem kept me searching for hours.